# How to show long text in tkinter tksheet cells?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been learning tkinter and found a module tksheet, which helps me to show the tables.
I am tinkering with the documentation, and try to create a simple table.

I encountered one problem, sometimes the text are long and I want to show the whole text in the table. (I can set geometry of root app, but I am talking about showing the full text in sheet).

**How to show the full text in tksheet table?**

## MWE

```py
%%writefile a.py

from tksheet import Sheet
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [10,20,30],
                   'col1': [100,200,300],
                   'col2': ['NY','TX','OH'],
                   'col3': ['This is very long sentence.']*3
                  })
lst_data = df.values.tolist()
headers = df.columns.tolist()

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("800x200")

win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

frame = tk.Frame()
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

sheet = Sheet(frame,data = lst_data, headers=headers)
sheet.enable_bindings()
sheet.highlight_rows(rows = [0], bg = 'yellow', fg = None)

frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")
sheet.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")

win.mainloop()
```

## Question: How to show the full text in cells?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With reference to issues in github: https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet/issues/9

I found the solution:

```
sheet.set_all_cell_sizes_to_text()
```